# Merge many PDFs into single multi-page file with web technologies

Tags: pdf, merge, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I have many single-page PDF files that need to be merged into one with many pages (PDFs are generated from HTML pages). Moreover it needs to be a cross-OS, cross-browser solution and independent on the backend technology used on the server (must work and be easy to install on Windows, Linux and OS X). I was thinking about merging the files with PDF.js (from Mozilla) but from what I've read it only renders proper PDF under Firefox and Chrome (so IE users are excluded, or not ?). Any other options to do this in a browser/web environment?
It'll be used in a commercial application so I also need a proper license if it's some third-party software.

Comment: I don't think client-side technologies are up to this at the moment. Can you give us some background why you don't wish to do this on the server?

Comment: as said previously, I can tell my users to install phantomjs, or nodejs, but I have no control of the backend technology they use, nor if it's a windows or unix server. That's why I need a solution that will work on any of them and not all libs work on every environment.

Comment: You didn't _quite_ say that, but alright `:)`... why not use a server-side technology that works in all environments? GhostScript runs on all of 'em.

Comment: Few problems with that one - license free only for non-commercial use, no mac sources, and not sure if it'll be able to generate pdf from html. It's best for me to update the question.

Comment: On the license question: from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript): _Ghostscript can be also licensed for use in proprietary projects for a fee_.

Comment: ok, but then each of my clients would have to buy a license when setting this up for themselves and that's a no-go for me.

Comment: Is that definitely the case? Could you not buy an integration license? (I've no idea, but it is worth checking).

Comment: No, because to some extend it can be used for free so then my company would lose money on the license. I think I'll check the pdf.js way, as it's reported to work on IE9 and for some time this may be sufficient.

Comment: I have removed nodejs from your tags since you do not want a server-side solution that you can implement yourself on nodejs. As for your mention of node in your comment as "I can tell my users to install phantomjs, or nodejs,..." you can also tell them to use other gazillion numbers of pdf tools. This is not even a programming question since you want a software not to develop one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this client side, unless you roll your own.  There's currently nothing that can handle this client side available.

Your best shot is to try to use something server side, like Python + [PyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/), which is quite cross platform.